# Changing Gnome Lock Screen

Tags: gnome, screen, lock

Ubuntu 13.04
Gnome Desktop: 3..6.2

Does anyone now if it is possible to add this specific lock theme with the above versions?  I can't find the "apps/gnome-screensaver" referenced  in the configuration editor.

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/NSA+Lock+Screen+%28Ubuntu+10.04%29?content=125033

Answer (score 0):

No, that lock screen was designed for Gnome/GTK 2. In Gnome 3, the screen saver functionality was removed since screen savers are mostly a relic from the days of CRT monitors.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Do you know of anyway to change the lock screen?

Comment: @DaleThomas Right now I do not know how. Thankfully,the feature has been added to Gnome 3.10 so you will soon have access to it. See the last paragraph in this article: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/10-best-features-gnome-3-10